# vue.js dynamically adding to a list of components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm having trouble dynamically adding to a list of components.

I've defined the list in the data element "things" of the vue document. For each object in "things" there is a component loaded onto the page

```
  data() {
    return {
      things: []
    }
  }
```

I use something like the code below to load each of the things on the page.

```
  <div v-for="thing in things" :key="thing.objectId">
```

Then I load in more elements and add them to the list

```
        let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
        vm.things = vm.things.concat(temp)
```

And when I run it in dev I get the following

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render
>   function.

Other then the error message, the code works in dev mode but crashes the browser when run in production.

I've narrowed it down to this code, there is a bit in the loop which prints out a heading which is the month the data belongs to, so it might say January, then list all the data under january, then onto the next month and so on

```
showDate(data) {
  this.currentDataMonth = helperfunctionsgetDate_format_month_year(data)
  if (this.currentDataMonth != this.currentmonth) {
    this.currentmonth = this.currentDataMonth
    return "<h2>" + this.currentmonth + "</h2>"
  } else {
    return ""
  }
```

Comment: where this adding to list happens? In vue method? Why u use vm then?

Comment: the vm variable is just a reference to the original this. It's within an ajax call and this gets rewritten which is why i changed it above to vm

Comment: create a codepen please

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by the fact that you both modify the state, and use the state from the same method.

> ```
> showDate(data) {
>   this.currentDataMonth = helperfunctionsgetDate_format_month_year(data) // set of the state
>   if (this.currentDataMonth != this.currentmonth) { // get of the state
>     this.currentmonth = this.currentDataMonth
>     return "<h2>" + this.currentmonth + "</h2>"
>   } else {
>     return ""
>   }
> ```

Since you directly use those variables inside your function, make them local to the function

```
showDate(data) {
  const currentDataMonth = helperfunctionsgetDate_format_month_year(data)
  if (currentDataMonth != undefined) {
    const currentmonth = currentDataMonth
    return "<h2>" + currentmonth + "</h2>"
  } else {
    return ""
  }
```

Since the purpose of the code is to list every month under its own heading, you should do that using a computed function to return a list of data per month, and use 2 loops to loop over that